# A question about 直る and 修理

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-usage

I am trying to say something like:

> Could you tell me where I could get my glasses repaired ?

My first try was to use 直れる (potential form of 直る) to say something like

> 直れるところ
>   place where something can get repaired

But here, without even considering that it sounds quite weird (if not utterly wrong), the “potential form” of 直る seems not to exist (save for a few compound verbs like 立ち直れる (get over sth)).

So, from this point, taking into account that `place where something can be repaired` uses passive voice I thought that it would be better to use passive.

> 眼鏡が直られるところ
>   place where glasses are/get repaired

So that the final sentence looks like this:

> 眼鏡が直れてもらえるところを教えてくださいませんか。
>   Could you tell me where I could get my glasses repaired?

And I think at this point that the above sentence is grammatically correct and conveys the right meaning. But I don't think it is really natural yet. Indeed, even if 直る seems to fit in this kind of situation, according to the dictionary, I don't get many hits on large database like google, weblio or bbcwj. In fact, 修理 seems to be used in that case.

So I reworded it with 修理:

> 眼鏡が修理されてもらえるところを教えてくださいませんか。or
>   眼鏡を修理させてもらえるところを教えてくださいませんか。

But here again, 修理される (be repaired) or 修理させる (have repaired) seems not to work so well in this context.

So here is my end sentence,

> 眼鏡が修理してもらえるところを教えてくださいませんか。

My question is multi-folded:

- Is my end sentence both grammatically correct and natural?
- Am I right in the fact that 直れる does not exist save for a few compound verbs?
- Am I right in what I said about 修理[する・される・させる]?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would say:

> 眼鏡を直してもらえるところを教えてくださいませんか。　　
>   Could you tell me where I could get my glasses repaired.

You don't say 「直れてもらう」. Use transitive 「直す」 + 「もらう」 -> 「直してもらう」, literally "have someone repair."

I don't think I have ever seen 「直れる」 outside compound verbs... I think we just use 「直る」 for both "be repaired" and "can be repaired".

> 眼鏡が直られるところ
>   place where glasses are/get repaired

The passive form of 「直す」("to repair") is 「直される」, so "where glasses are repaired" would literally translate to 「眼鏡が直されるところ」, but we don't really say 「眼鏡が直されるところを教えてくれませんか」. In daily conversation, you'd rather say:

> 「眼鏡を/が直せるところを教えてくれませんか。」
>   (Lit. Can you tell me where I can repair my glasses?)

... even though you're not going to repair them by yourself.

---

眼鏡が修理されてもらえるところ is unnatural and doesn't make much sense.
眼鏡を修理させてもらえるところ is natural, but it would mean "where I am allowed to / they let me repair my glasses (by myself)".

Your last sentence:

> 眼鏡が修理してもらえるところを教えてくださいませんか。

looks perfect to me. You could also say 「眼鏡を修理してもらえるところを・・・」.
(Both 「を」 and 「が」 sound fine since there's a potential もらえる.)

Comment: Thank you very much. And yes, I forget to replace が by を in the last sentence...